# Nginx infinite redirect using try_files

Tags: nginx, react-router

I'm trying to use react-router for my routing needs. I've tried to configure nginx to use index.html when I hit anything under the /app route. However when I go to the localhost:8000/app route I keep on getting redirected back to the  localhost:8000/app.

```
server {
listen       8000;
server_name  localhost;

#access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

location /app/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   html;
}
}
```